# Using Animate/Hover/Ease in Jquery to change color of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I'm trying to accomplish is a hover feature that will change or ease in the color of each letter - the first letter finishing before the next - as well as div boxes that will appear while hovered either over the left or right side (i did this with css).  I split the page into 2 wrappers - left/right - and I'm looking to do something similar to http://www.dada-data.net/en/hub .. I hope this can be accomplished without canvas, and just jquery.

See https://jsfiddle.net/jmbrock/7q2p17vb/1/ for what I have.  I believe an easing function would put be on the right track, but i can't get it to work.

JS

```
$("#left-wrap").on("mouseover",function(){
    $(".letter").animate({color:"#FF4500"},'slow');
}).on("mouseleave",function(){
    $(".letter").animate({color:"grey"},'slow');
});

$("#right-wrap").on("mouseover",function(){
    $(".letter").animate({color:"#FF4500"},'slow');
}).on("mouseleave",function(){
    $(".letter").animate({color:"blue"},'slow');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: colors cannot be animated using jQuery animate, as per https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp and it is too broad of a question to ask "I want x. How do I do it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add transition to the div so that slow color change on hover to your #left-wrap and #right-wrap 
and changed your .skills visibility from hidden to opacity 0(which will be 1 on hover)

```
transition:0.5s all ease;
```

DEMO : http://jsbin.com/kufinakuda/1/edit?html,css,js,output